# Why i still getting an undefined return here?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

Im trying to get the Value from my Firestore DB Async Function **cvUpload**. But no matter how long i wait for the value it is still undefined if i call it on my component.

I see many have the same issues with async await and promises . But i really not able to solve it. I really need some hints here.

**DatabaseService.ts**

```
export class DatabaseService {

constructor(
   private dbService : DatabaseService ) {}


async cvUpload (id : string) {
   const userRef = collection(this.db, this.user_db)
   const q = query(userRef, where("id", "==", id));
   const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(doc.data().cv) /// False (Thats correct)
     return   doc.data().cv;
});
}
```

**DashboardComponent.ts**

```
  constructor(
    private dbService : DatabaseService ) {
   }

   async ngOnInit() {
    await this.checkCV('uyDer0BxoVekGU2XnYa3Xm77nm03')
   }


    async checkCV(id : any)  {
     let result = await this.dbService.cvUpload(id) /// This shoud return FALSE
     }
```

I am grateful for any help or tip that will take me further here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the actual mistake lies in the cvUpload method. You're actually returning nothing from the cvUpload function. Returning something inside a Array.forEach() doesn't count as cvUpload's return value.

Maybe you should just return

```js
async cvUpload(id: string) {
        const userRef = collection(this.db, this.user_db)
        const q = query(userRef, where("id", "==", id));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    
        return querySnapshot.docs[0].data().cv;
    };
```

Comment: Just note that in this code we're just returning the first doc's cv data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(doc.data().cv) /// False (Thats correct)
     return   doc.data().cv;
...
```

You are doing a *forEach*...I guess that you are waiting to recive just 1 only item... But if not, be careful because you only would treat the first element...

Any way, assuming that you will only have one element in there:

Probably you are having problem with the "falsy" returning value...Could you try to treat all of these with an object, to check if it still happens?.

Something like this:

DatabaseService.ts

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
     console.log(doc.data().cv) /// False (Thats correct)
     const result: {result: boolean};
     result = { result: doc?.data()?.cv ?? false, };
     return result;
});
```

DashboardComponent.ts

```
async checkCV(id : any)  {
     const {result} = await this.dbService.cvUpload(id) /// This shoud return FALSE
}
```